# Does Redis keep all chars from prefixed kind of keys?

Tags: redis

I may have 100mi long, but partially static keys like:

`someReal...LongStaticPrefix:12345`
`someReal...LongStaticPrefix:12`
`someReal...LongStaticPrefix:123456`

Where only the last part of the key is dynamic, the rest is static.

Does Redis keep all keys long or does it make an internal alias or something like that?
Should I worry about storage or performance?

Or is it better if I make internal alias do the keys to keep them short?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis does keep the whole key. This long prefix will impact your memory usage.

Given redis uses a hash map to store the keys, the performance impact is low. Hash map load factor is usually between 0.5 and 1. This means usually there is just one or two keys per hash slot. So the performance impact is the extra network payload for the long key, the longer effort to hash it, and the longer comparison in the hash slot with one or two keys. It's likely negligible unless your prefix is really really long

Consider a shorter key prefix.

Before considering using a hash structure (HSET), consider if you are using redis cluster or if you may need to eventually. A single hash key cannot be sharded.

A minor optimization : Consider using a suffix for faster compares at the hash slot chain

Comment: What do you mean by suffix? like ```123:mykey``` ?

Comment: Yeah, when Redis is testing if it has the right key, it does a mem compare. The faster it finds a difference the faster it moves. Putting the difference at the beginning makes this compare quicker. A minor optimization